# Extract numbers that does not follow a pattern python

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a CSV file which contains many columns for payments.

There's one column column called `control_number`. This is unique identifier for every transaction and it follows a pattern, all control numbers must.

Starts with `991` and contains 12 digits. Now, I want to extract list of all control numbers that do not follow a pattern.

Sample data:

| control_number |
| --- |
| 991100267615 |
| 991100267632 |
| 991100267636 |
| 992100267635 |
| 991100267672 |
| 991100267697 |
| 995100267696 |
| 991100267726 |
| 991100267743 |
| 991100267761 |
| 991100267771 |
| 990100267779 |
| 991100267768 |
| 991100267811 |
| 991100267813 |
| 991100267814 |

Desired output should be like this:

| control_number |
| --- |
| 992100267635 |
| 995100267696 |
| 990100267779 |

Here's what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("transactions.csv")
df.head(5)
invalid_transaction = df['control_number']
re.findall(r"(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)", invalid_transaction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the values are already 12-digit numbers, you do not need a regex here, you can use `Series.str.startswith`:

```py
df = df[~df["control_number"].astype(str).str.startswith("991")]
```

Here is a minified test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'control_number':[991100267615, 991100267632, 991100267636, 992100267635]})
```

Output:

```py
>>> df[~df["control_number"].astype(str).str.startswith("991")]
   control_number
3    992100267635
```

Note the `~` sign means a negation, only those records are taken that do not start with `991`.

With regex, you can also use `Series.str.contains`:

```py
df = df[~df["control_number"].astype(str).str.contains(r"^991[0-9]{9}$")]
```

Or, if you want to use *positive* regex logic (extract what does not match the pattern):

```py
df = df[df["control_number"].astype(str).str.contains(r"^(?!991[0-9]{9}$)")]
```

Here, the regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!991[0-9]{9}$)`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is `991` and any nine more digits till end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
print(df[~df["control_number"].astype(str).str.match(r"991")])
```

Prints:

```
    control_number
3     992100267635
6     995100267696
11    990100267779
```

---

Or more specific:

```py
print(df[~df["control_number"].astype(str).str.match(r"991\d{9}$")])
```